# Javascript API fb_dtsg variable curious

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My name is Kim Donghoon

Facebook on my page will attempt to use the message function.

But I wonder fb_dtsg JS variables.

We do not know the value of fb_dtsg.

And fb_dtsg Is there any way I can get the value?

```
 {
  "user":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "locale":"ko_KR",
  "method":"GET",
  "svn_rev":538443,
  "vip":"69.171.234.64",
  "static_base":"https:\/\/s-static.ak.facebook.com\/",
  "www_base":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/",
  "rep_lag":2,
  "fb_dtsg":"xxxxxxxx",                           //I wonder is this
  "ajaxpipe_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "lhsh":"vAQG-Gub0",
  "tracking_domain":"https:\/\/pixel.facebook.com",
  "retry_ajax_on_network_error":"1",
  "html5_audio":"1",
  "fbid_emoticons":"1"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are dealing with JSON so what you have to do is parse it. There are libraries that can do it for you or you can use the eval function.

```
var object = eval('(' + data + ')')
```

You basically pass the JSON data into the eval function, but make sure you add parenthesis and make sure to wrap them in quotes or you will encounter an error.

This effectively parses the JSON and makes it an object so now you can access fb_dtsg like this

```
object.fb_dtsg
```

Comment: Thank you, James Fair
What I want you to
fb_dtsg variables Did you know?